# Issue with .Rprofile file when trying to upload to RPubs

Tags: r, rstudio

From what I can gather there is a well documented issue with uploading Rpubs to RStudio. The solution is to create a .Rprofile and with an additional line:

```
options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal")
```

and then put the .Rprofile file in your working directory, and restart the program. My issue is that when I attempt this and start up RStudio I am presented with the error:

```
Error in assign(".popath", popath, .BaseNamespaceEnv) : 
cannot change value of locked binding for '.popath'
```

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong? What have I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is provided by a careful rereading of http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/25030_8e9c9ffc3b3c423d9381d81543423502.html

"Put in options(rpubs.upload.method = “internal”) and no other text at all". Meaning that this line of code is the only code present in the .Rprofile file.

Previously I had been adding the line to a copy of the rest of the Rprofile text. The unnecessary code was the culprit.